# Simple newbe Q: how to set output?

Tags: stanford-nlp

Dear Stanford NLP folks - (a) thanks for the great tool; (b) I'm sure this is simple but can't figure out how to get the commandline call to push output to a file (rather than to screen). [FQQ](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/parser-faq.shtml) says use the `-writeOutfiles` option...but can't find the syntax.

Example of my command-line code:

```
java -mx200m  -cp "*;" edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser -outputFormat "wordsAndTags,penn,typedDependencies" edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz c:/jwm/abstract.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add:

```
-writeOutputFiles
```

to the command it should write an output file corresponding to each input file with ".stp" added at the end.